# How to use RLIKE/REGEXP patterns .* in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rlike

Question: Query the list of CITY names from STATION which have vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, and u) as both their first and last characters. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

I found an answer edited by @Mureinik, (thank you! it is very helpful!)

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

I am confused that, the question is asking about both their first and last characters is aeiou, why can't I just use

```
CITY RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU][aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

However, when I take out the . and *, it is shown wrong answer.

Why do we need to use . and * in this question?
Does . and * always use together?

There is another question:
Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*$';
```

Why use [aeiouAEIOU] twice in the first question, only use once in the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CITY RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU][aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

This will only match city names with exactly two characters, both vowels.

In regular expressions, a set of characters in square brackets like `[aeiouAEIOU]` matches exactly one character.

You have nothing in between the two square-bracketed sets, so there must not be any characters in between in the strings that match.